# Can I install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 32 bit?

Tags: 32-bit

Is it possible to install VS Code on 32 bit ubuntu machine? if yes please provide the steps.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is 64-bit only. I have no idea why people are so eager to install it, after all, it is just an editor, not an IDE. Sublime is better than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry You can't do  that.

You can't install a 64-bit app on  32bit machine.

And from [Microsoft download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), it does show download for 64-bit only.

---

**Update:**

Now it's available a 32 bit app. you can download the *.deb* from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux32_deb)

Answer (score 8):

It's possible now, Microsoft released  [Linux 32bit version](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads)

Comment: Where can I find download links to old versions?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit

You can use Ubuntu Make to download and install Visual Studio Code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Then install Visual Studio Code:

```
umake ide visual-studio-code
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run it installing a nodejs package called electron.

```
npm install electron-prebuilt -g
```

then cd to your downloaded VScode folder,

```
cd resources
```

then

```
electron app
```

that's all! Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

The latest 32bit version was on May 2019:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35

Answer (score 0):

**This specifically for ubuntu 16.04**

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

you may have to force to install

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

go to the link [linux 32-bit version](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux32_deb)

and after downloading from your terminal go to your Downloads folder

```
cd Downloads
sudo gdebi code_1.3.1-1468330706_i386.deb
```